# How to properly update copy of struct

Tags: c, struct

So I have this button.h file that looks something like this:

```c
#ifndef SCGUI_BUTTON_H
#define SCGUI_BUTTON_H

#include <SCGUI/styles.h>

struct SCGUI_Button {
    SCGUI_ButtonStyle style;
    bool hovered;
}; 

struct SCGUI_Button scgui_new_button();
void scgui_draw_button(struct SCGUI_Button button);

#endif
```

And then I have this button.c file that looks basically like this:

```c
#include <SCGUI/styles.h>
#include <SCGUI/button.h>


struct SCGUI_Button scgui_new_button() {
    struct SCGUI_Button button;

    button.hovered = false;

    return button;
}

void scgui_draw_button(struct SCGUI_Button self) {


    if (button_hovered(self.area, app.mouse_pos.x, app.mouse_pos.y)) {
        //Set style here using this syntax
        self.style = (SCGUI_ButtonStyle) {
            .background_color = self.style.hover.background_color,
            .font_color = self.style.hover.font_color,
            .font_family = self.style.hover.font_family == NULL || strlen(self.style.hover.font_family) == 0 ? "res/Roboto.ttf" : self.style.hover.font_family,
            .font_size = self.style.hover.font_size == 0 ? self.style.font_size : self.style.hover.font_size
        };

        self.hovered = true;

        scgui_set_style(self);
    } else {
        set_default_styles(self); //Revert styles
        scgui_set_style(self);
    }

    //Draw stuff, etc.
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(app.renderer,
        self.style.background_color.red, 
        self.style.background_color.green, 
        self.style.background_color.blue,
        255
    );
}
```

So all of this code works almost perfectly. All my styling code works perfectly, but there's one main issue, which happens with the `button.hovered` struct member. I initialized `button.hovered` to false in the main `scgui_new_button()` initialization function. However, when I want to set the value of `button.hovered` to anything else in the `scgui_draw_button()` function, the value won't be updated. I believe that the issue is that the struct parameter in that function just creates a copy of the `SCGUI_Button` struct and doesn't actually update the main struct value in the initialization function. I also know that I can use a pointer such as `SCGUI_Button *self` as the function parameter for the `scgui_draw_button()` function to properly update the `self->hovered` value, but this messes up and breaks all my other code within that function.

I'm stuck here, because I don't want to rewrite all my styling code in the `scgui_draw_button()` function and use pointers just to update one struct method. I've been thinking about other ways to solve this issue but I'm completely stuck. Any insight or ideas on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The "works almost perfectly" thinking will slow you down (invalid logic).  Any changes you make to the copy `self`, as you said, will not be visible to the caller.  You have 2 options: change the type of self to a pointer, or return a `struct SCGUI_Button` and have caller update it's value `button = scgui_draw_button(button);`.  The latter will be slow if the object you copy back is large.

Comment: "_I'm stuck here, because I don't want_"... That's how it goes when you **want to** use some clever but inappropriate C syntax... The function `scgui_new_button()` is returning a mostly uninitialsed structure... Is this what you **want**? (If you **want** to initialise a struct with the "dot syntax", then do that and copy the values to the block **pointed to by the passed pointer**.

Comment: You said it yourself, you're updating a local copy,,, you're going to have to refactor something. Find and replace can help.

Comment: Search and replace `self.` to `self->` is rather trivial.

Comment: Recommend passing pointers of structs to functions anyway, copying the struct each time is more expensive. Make it a `const` pointer if the function isn't supposed to modify it.

Comment: it is the same effect as if you would have function foo(int n) and inside the function you do n = 1;  it has no effect outside the function since the assignment is to a copy of the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any changes you make to the copy self, as you said, will not be visible to the caller.  Here are your options:

1. Change the signature to pass `self` as a pointer:

```
void scgui_draw_button(struct SCGUI_Button *self);
```

This means you have to change the use of self in the function `self.` to self->`.  Callers have to call with the address (`&button`) instead of the object (`button`).  This should be default choice.

2. Change the signature to return, by value, the modified data:

```
struct SCGUI_Button scgui_draw_button(struct SCGUI_Button self);
```

Change the implicit `return` at the end or explicit `return` to `return self;`.  Callers would now update their copy along these lines: `button = scgui_draw_button(button)`.  If `self` is large you are copying the data twice and hence could be slow.  On the positive side, caller knows that their `button` is not being modified.  This is sometimes referred to as a functional style.

3. Change the signature to accept a pointer to a constant value, and return a pointer to the modified data:

```
struct SCGUI_Button *scgui_draw_button(const struct SCGUI_Button *self);
```

This is a variant of the above but we now pass in `self` via a pointer to a constant value (so we don't have to copy it).  In your function you now have to allocate dynamic memory (via `malloc()`) for the copy.  This tasks the caller with deallocating the returned value.  This should be your least favored option.